# checkpoint file for different instances of tensorflow program

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm tweaking parameters in my tensorflow script to determine best performance.

Basically I'm running at the same time different instances of the same script with different parameters but saving the model with different names

I thought that changing the name in the `saver` would be enough. So if I run 3 independent instances of the script **each one** would have a different filename, e.g.,

```
saver.save(session,"./whatever_param1.ckpt"), 
saver.save(session,"./whatever_param2.ckpt"),
saver.save(session,"./whatever_param3.ckpt")
```

I'm actually getting different `.meta`, `.index` and `.data-00000-of-00001` files.

What I don't understand is the file named `checkpoint`. All instances of my script running concurrently seem to write to the same `checkpoint` file.

I think I'm messing up the results for the different instances of the script running at the same time.

Could you please let me know why only one `checkpoint` file is created even if a pass a different name to the `saver`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) documentation

In particular this part:

> That protocol buffer is stored in a file named 'checkpoint' next to the checkpoint files.
>
> If you create several savers, you can specify a different filename for the protocol buffer file in the call to save().

And in `save()`
the argument to specify is:

> latest_filename: Optional name for the protocol buffer file that will contains the list of most recent checkpoint filenames. That file, kept in the same directory as the checkpoint files, is automatically managed by the saver to keep track of recent checkpoints. Defaults to 'checkpoint'.

so the solution is:

```
saver.save(session, "./whatever_param1.ckpt", latest_filename='checkpoint_param1')
```